# MariaDB Docker Container keeps restarting

Tags: docker, web-applications, mariadb

I have a Web-Application running within a couple of docker containers. One of them contains my database running mariadb:11.2.2

**EDIT:**
This is the relevant part of compose.yml file:

```
services:
  db-appointment:
    container_name: db-appointment
    image: mariadb:11.2.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db-appointment
    volumes:
      - db-appointment-data:/var/lib/mysql

  discovery:
    container_name: discovery
    build: ./discovery
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"

  calendar:
    container_name: calendar
    build: ./calendar
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://discovery:8761/eureka
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mariadb://db-appointment:3306/db-appointment?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    depends_on:
      - discovery
      - db-appointment

  ui:
    container_name: ui
    build: ./ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://discovery:8761/eureka
    depends_on:
      - discovery
      - calendar

volumes:
  db-appointment-data:
```

In the beginning I can start all the containers without any problem and the application
runs as expected (saving and loading data from db, ...) but after a couple of hours or
days the database container keeps restarting and whenever i access the container via
`docker exec -it db-xxx mariadb --user root -pasdf` it says that there is no database.

I've been searching for answers for a while now and I cannot really find a solution for
my problem.

- I tried different mariadb image versions
- Triple checked the code itself if something is causing overflows, ...
- checked the available disk space
- ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**

The following contains the docker logs:

```
2024-01-14 11:13:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2024-01-14 11:13:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-01-14 11:13:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2024-01-14 11:13:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259 as process 1
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=405328
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 405328; transaction id 512
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240114 11:13:16
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-01-14 11:13:16 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2024-01-14 12:38:29 63 [Warning] Aborted connection 63 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '45.79.181.179' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 13:12:28 91 [Warning] Aborted connection 91 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.104.210.105' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 13:27:58 105 [Warning] Aborted connection 105 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '198.74.56.46' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 13:49:28 126 [Warning] Aborted connection 126 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '35.190.199.12' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 13:49:28 127 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'34.78.6.216' (using password: NO)
2024-01-14 15:14:31 188 [Warning] Aborted connection 188 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '152.32.245.44' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 15:14:41 189 [Warning] Aborted connection 189 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '152.32.245.44' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 15:14:44 190 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'152.32.245.44' (using password: NO)
2024-01-14 15:14:58 191 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'152.32.245.44' (using password: YES)
2024-01-14 16:17:31 232 [Warning] Aborted connection 232 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '64.227.123.18' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 17:17:54 273 [Warning] Aborted connection 273 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '198.235.24.55' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 18:31:08 314 [Warning] Aborted connection 314 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '74.82.47.37' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 19:41:56 375 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.64.78' (using password: NO)
2024-01-14 19:41:56 376 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.64.78' (using password: YES)
2024-01-14 19:42:12 378 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.64.78' (using password: NO)
2024-01-14 19:42:12 379 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.64.78' (using password: YES)
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: root[root] @  [94.156.64.78]): Normal shutdown
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240114 19:42:18
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 554561; transaction id 731
2024-01-14 19:42:18 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete

2024-01-14 19:42:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2024-01-14 19:42:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-01-14 19:42:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2024-01-14 19:42:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259 as process 1
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=554561
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 554561; transaction id 732
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240114 19:42:19
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-01-14 19:42:19 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2024-01-14 22:27:22 3419 [Warning] Aborted connection 3419 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.241.214.13' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-14 23:05:56 4346 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.71.54' (using password: NO)
2024-01-15  0:11:23 5915 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'185.209.196.144' (using password: NO)
2024-01-15  0:58:24 7046 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.71.57' (using password: NO)
2024-01-15  4:47:41 12545 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.71.112' (using password: NO)
2024-01-15  4:47:41 12546 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.71.112' (using password: YES)
2024-01-15  4:48:02 12556 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.71.112' (using password: NO)
2024-01-15  4:48:02 12557 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'94.156.71.112' (using password: YES)
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: root[root] @  [94.156.71.112]): Normal shutdown
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240115  4:48:04
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 566404; transaction id 755
2024-01-15  4:48:04 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete

2024-01-15 04:48:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2024-01-15 04:48:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-01-15 04:48:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2024-01-15 04:48:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259 as process 1
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=566404
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 566404; transaction id 756
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240115  4:48:05
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-01-15  4:48:05 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2024-01-15  5:14:17 631 [Warning] Aborted connection 631 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'connecting host' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-15  6:44:51 2804 [Warning] Aborted connection 2804 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '167.94.145.57' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2024-01-15  6:54:55 3047 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'185.65.135.190' (using password: NO)
2024-01-15  7:47:30 4310 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'169.150.196.30' (using password: NO)
```

I see that it says `[Note] mariadbd (initiated by: root[root] @  [94.156.71.112]): Normal shutdown` but I cannot really figure out what exactly triggered the shutdown.

Comment: What is the contents of the container logs?

Comment: Usually it is problems with db folder permissions. Please check UID on your local machine and UID in db container.

Comment: Named volume like you have are less likely to have permission problems. If there container was initialized before MYSQL_DATABASE was set, then it won't contain a database. Most environment variables are only related to the first initialization. I can't explain the restarting or shutdown without the container logs `docker logs {containername}`. Please edit the question to include it. Also [MYSQL_TCP_PORT not an official container env variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-docker-official-image-environment-variables/). Changing from default is unlikely to work.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I attached the docker logs